# Bash deleting a specific row in .dat file

Tags: linux, bash

So, I have this assignment which requires me to delete a certain line from a `.dat` file. Now my file is basically a phone book. I have a Bash script that adds the ID, name, last name, phone number, address, etc., to the `.dat` file. Now one of the flags is supposed to be `-delete` and it takes the parameter `id`. So, basically I need to implement the function where I'd put `./phonebook.sh -delete -id 7` and it would delete the row where the id is 7.

I tried using `sed` and `awk`, but nothing is working and it's frustrating. My current code for that short script (`delete.sh`) is:

```
id=$1
sed "/$id/d" phonebook.dat
```

Comment: Hard to help when we don't know what the format of this ".dat" file is...

Comment: In what way is your `sed` not working?  For the simple case, that will indeed filter the input and delete a matching line.  It may remove more lines than you want, and there are certainly non-trivial edge cases on which it will break, but you haven't really given enough details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

On Mac:

```
sed -i '' -e "/$id/d" phonebook.dat
```

Otherwise:

```
sed -i -e "/$id/d" phonebook.dat
```

By default, `sed` will output the results to stdout.  So, your command was working, but the output wasn't going back into the file.  The `-i` flag says that the file should be replaced with the results.  `-i` is also meant to backup the original file.  For example:

```
sed -i .bk -e "/$id/d" phonebook.dat
```

The above will create a copy of the original called:  `phonebook.dat.bk`.  However, to do in place replacement without a backup, you can specify no value for `-i`.  On the MAC, sed really really really wants a value, so you can pass it an empty string ( making sure there is a space between the -i and the empty quotes ).

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it. It works now :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm making some assumptions because I don't know what the format of your dat file is.  I'll assume that the `id` field is the first field and the file is comma delimited.  If I'm wrong, you should be able to modify the below to fit your needs.

I personally like to use `grep -v` for this problem.  From the `--help`:

```
-v, --invert-match        select non-matching lines
```

Running this will output every line of a file that does not match your pattern.

```
id="$1"
grep -v "^${id}," phonebook.dat > phonebook.temp
mv phonebook.temp phonebook.dat
```

The pattern consists of

- `^`: Beginning of the line
- `${id}`: Your variable
- `,`: Our assumed delimiter

The reason for specifying the beginning of the line to the first delimiter is to avoid deleting entries where the entered id (`$1`) is a substring of other ids.  You wouldn't want to enter 22 and delete id 22 as well as id 122.